# I want to print out some values from 2-d array C++

Tags: c++

I want to input data from txt file.
the file contains 2-d array [5][5]
how can i print out the any value i want?
i don't want to print out the whole 5*5 data

```
#include <iostream>

#include <fstream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;



int main()
{

    double distance[5][5] ;
    string line;

     ifstream ratefile;
                   ratefile.open("a.txt");
     ofstream file;
     if (ratefile.is_open())
      {
    while (! ratefile.eof() )
    {
      getline (ratefile,line);
   ratefile.getline(distance, 25, '*');

    cout << "\nDistance [0][0]" << ": " << distance[0][0];
    cout << "\nDistance [0][1]" << ": " << distance[0][1];
    cout << "\nDistance [0][2]" << ": " << distance[0][2];
    cout << "\nDistance [0][3]" << ": " << distance[0][3];
    cout << "\nDistance [1][0]" << ": " << distance[1][0];
    cout << "\nDistance [1][1]" << ": " << distance[1][1];
    cout << "\nDistance [1][2]" << ": " << distance[1][2];
    cout << "\nDistance [1][3]" << ": " << distance[1][3];

    cout << endl;


    cin.get();



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you miss some lines in the code?

Comment: As a programmer, if I would like to print out the values I want, I would print out the values I want. If you want somebody to answer the question, you need to specify what the problem is...

Comment: What does "the any value I want" mean? Which value do you want to print?

Comment: BTW looping on `!stream.eof()` is wrong: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.5

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to output one value and the user should be able to choose a value, you can do something like this:

```
int x, y;

cin >> x;
cin >> y;

cout << "\nDistance [" << x << "][" << y << "]" << ": " << distance[x][y];
```

But you should check if the user enter valid numbers (0 <= x < 4 and 0 <= y < 4)

Answer (score 0):

There is part of the code missing, but you are printing values you want. Simply remove the lines you don't want to print.

Of course you can also use variables:

```
int x = 2,y = 2;
cout << endl << "Distance [" << x << "][" << y << "] : " << distance[x][y];
```